# DAX : Allocate Inventory to Open Orders

Tags: sql, powerbi, dax, powerquery, powerbi-desktop

I am trying to allocate inventory items to open orders in DAX, PowerBi. The idea is to allocate all the available inventory to the oldest order first, then allocate the remaining inventory to the second oldest, etc. until the inventory is depleted. The inventory can be depleted even if the open order is not completely satisfied.

Please check the attached picture as an example for the allocations below

[image: Allocation Example]

I tried adding a column in the open order table using the Calculate function but the results were not correct at all. It didn't do any allocations, it just summed up the inventory.

```
CALCULATE (
        [QOH],
        FILTER (
            ALL ( 'Open Orders'[Parent Name] ),
            'Open Orders'[Due Date] <= MAX ( ( 'Open Orders'[Due Date] ) )
        )
    )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tricky part here is calculating what was ordered before the date on the current row but you can do that by looking at the sum for previous due dates.

This should work as a calculated column:

```
Inventory Allocation =
VAR TotalInventory =
    LOOKUPVALUE ( Inventory[Qty On Hand], Inventory[Item], 'Open Orders'[Item] )
VAR AlreadyOrdered =
    CALCULATE (
        SUM ( 'Open Orders'[Qty Open] ),
        ALL ( 'Open Orders' ),
        Inventory[Item] = EARLIER ( 'Open Orders'[Item] ),
        'Open Orders'[Due Date] < EARLIER ( 'Open Orders'[Due Date] )
    )
RETURN
    IF (
        AlreadyOrdered > TotalInventory,
        0,
        MIN ( 'Open Orders'[Qty Open], TotalInventory - AlreadyOrdered )
    )
```

---

**Edit:**

In the `AlreadyOrdered` definition, the `ALL` argument says to remove all the row/filter context from the table and the following arguments specify the filtering I do want and is equivalent to the [`REMOVEFILTERS` funcion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/removefilters-function-dax) inside of a `CALCULATE`.

The [`EARLIER` function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/earlier-function-dax) is often confusing to people as it has nothing to do with dates but refers to the earlier row context so I can refer to the value in the current row of the table while writing a condition inside a `CALCULATE`. You could use variables instead:

```
Inventory Allocation =
VAR TotalInventory =
    LOOKUPVALUE ( Inventory[Qty On Hand], Inventory[Item], 'Open Orders'[Item] )
VAR CurrItem = 'Open Orders'[Item]
VAR CurrDate = 'Open Orders'[Due Date]
VAR AlreadyOrdered =
    CALCULATE (
        SUM ( 'Open Orders'[Qty Open] ),
        REMOVEFILTERS ( 'Open Orders' ),
        Inventory[Item] = CurrItem,
        'Open Orders'[Due Date] < CurrDate
    )
RETURN
    IF (
        AlreadyOrdered > TotalInventory,
        0,
        MIN ( 'Open Orders'[Qty Open], TotalInventory - AlreadyOrdered )
    )
```

Comment: Thanks Alexis! This answered my question. Great use of variables, I need to start learning variables on DAX.

Comment: They're very handy and make for much more readable code most of the time.

Comment: Do you have any recommendations for tutorials or documentation on how use variables ?

Comment: No specific references handy. Use them to simplify and when you want to reuse the same calculation multiple times.

Comment: @AlexisOlson good answer! Could you please also share with us a pseudo-algorithm for your solution, or adding some comments? Especially, why do you need to use EARLIER and what is its effect? Thank you :)

Comment: Thanks for the extra clarifications! I have used the functions and it works as expected, which is great. But in some instances the allocations is not accurate, for example there is a quantity of 1 available and it allocates 1 to an order and another 1 to another order. In this particular example the two orders are for two different customers but is due on the same day. Is there a way to get the allocations to allocate even if it is for the same day to different customer, ship to locations, etc.? But basically every order line will get one allocation.

Comment: That added complexity not present in your example is outside the scope of this question but feel free to open a new one. The key to the answer though will be deciding how to allocate if you have multiple customers with the same order date/time but insufficient quantity to fulfill both orders.