# DAX : Allocate Inventory to Open Orders (Extra Complexity)

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery, powerbi-desktop

I am trying to allocate inventory items to open orders in DAX, PowerBi. The idea is to allocate all the available inventory to the oldest order first, then allocate the remaining inventory to the second oldest, etc. until the inventory is depleted. The inventory can be depleted even if the open order is not completely satisfied.

I already asked a similar question in this matter, I received a great answer and the results were great. Now I am adding extra complexity to the question, on how to decide and allocate in case of having multiple customers or ship to locations with the same order date but insufficient quantity to fulfill multiple orders.

Please check the attached picture as an example for the allocations below

[image: Extra Complicity Allocation]

The initial question is here:

[DAX : Allocate Inventory to Open Orders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61063251/dax-allocate-inventory-to-open-orders#)

the answer for the initial question is here:

```
Inventory Allocation =
VAR TotalInventory =
    LOOKUPVALUE ( Inventory[Qty On Hand], Inventory[Item], 'Open Orders'[Item] )
VAR AlreadyOrdered =
    CALCULATE (
        SUM ( 'Open Orders'[Qty Open] ),
        ALL ( 'Open Orders' ),
        Inventory[Item] = EARLIER ( 'Open Orders'[Item] ),
        'Open Orders'[Due Date] < EARLIER ( 'Open Orders'[Due Date] )
    )
RETURN
    IF (
        AlreadyOrdered > TotalInventory,
        0,
        MIN ( 'Open Orders'[Qty Open], TotalInventory - AlreadyOrdered )
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this when there is an order in your customer & Location. E.g. CustNr (Nr.) & Location (Alphabetic)

Because there is an order you can make the following change:

```
    VAR AlreadyOrdered =
        CALCULATE (
            SUM ( 'Open Orders'[Qty Open] ),
            FILTER ( 'Open Orders' ,
            Inventory[Item] = EARLIER ( 'Open Orders'[Item] ),
            'Open Orders'[Due Date] < EARLIER ( 'Open Orders'[Due Date]) &&
            Inventory[CustNr] < EARLIER (Inventory[CustNr]) &&
            Inventory[Location] < EARLIER (Inventory[Location]))
        )
```

Note: To keep the overview I propose **not** to work with EARLIER but instead use variables:

```
VAR curItem = Inventory[Item] 
VAR curDueDate = 'Open Orders'[Due Date]
VAR curCustNr = Inventory[CustNr]
VAR curLocation = Inventory[Location]

VAR TotalInventory =
    LOOKUPVALUE ( Inventory[Qty On Hand], curItem, 'Open Orders'[Item] )
VAR AlreadyOrdered =
        CALCULATE (
            SUM ( 'Open Orders'[Qty Open] ),
            ALL ( 'Open Orders' ),
            Inventory[Item] = curItem  ),
            'Open Orders'[Due Date] < curDueDate  &&
            Inventory[CustNr] < curCustNr  &&
            Inventory[Location] < curLocation )
        )
```

It is essential that there is always an order (sorting) in your columns else this is not working.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation Aldert! 

I tried the && but that didn't work, and I tried to have the Customer in the Calculate function, but that didn't work either. 

Var AlreadyOrdered = 
    CALCULATE(
     SUM('Open Orders'[Qty Open]), ALL('Open Orders'), 
        'INV'[Item Number] = EARLIER('Open Orders'[Item]),
        'Open Orders'[Due Date] < EARLIER( 'Open Orders'[Due Date] ),
        'Open Orders'[Customer] < EARLIER('Open Orders'[Customer])
        )

Comment: I have upated the top answer by using a filter, can you try that?

Comment: I tried the edited code but that didn't work. 
Also I am adding this as a column not as a measure. So variables that are not from the same table don't work, e.g. curItem = Inventory[Item].